# How to deal with type error of index like this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

when training data of paper Estimating People Flows to Better Count Them in Crowded Scenes, it came with some problem with `index = int(img_name.split('.')[0])` as the pictures show, index 130(1) can not be change to type int, it said 'invalid literal for int () with base '130(1).

It's strange that I have run the code over times, but the first several times I ran it, it said that the problem is 'invalid literal for int () with base  '049(1)'

Here is the detail:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 253, in <module>
    main()
  File "train.py", line 58, in main
    train(train_list, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "train.py", line 91, in train
    for i,(prev_img, img, post_img, prev_target, target, post_target ) in enumerate(train_loader):
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 435, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 475, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/project/dataset.py", line 30, in __getitem__
    prev_img,img,post_img,prev_target, target, post_target = load_data(img_path,self.train)
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/project/image.py", line 12, in load_data
    index = int(img_name.split('.')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '49(1)'
```

part of original code:

```py
def load_data(img_path,train = True):
   img_folder = os.path.dirname(img_path)
   img_name = os.path.basename(img_path)
   # print(img_name.split('.')[0])
   index = int(img_name.split('.')[0]) #
```

How can I deal with the problem and train the model successfully? Is the only way for me is to modify the label of image in dataset directly?

I first tried to replace the '(' and ')' with numbers like '000',but I soon realized that it will cause mismatch between the index and label. When I try to find the image according to index

[image]

I could not find ones whose name is 49(1) and 130(1).

Comment: Please don't post images of your code and tracebacks, but instead post them as raw text between code blocks (\`\`\`). Couldn't you just get rid of the digit in braces by simply doing `name = img_name.split('.')[0]; index = int(name[:name.index('(')])`?

Comment: sorry, it's my first time to use the platform and I am not clear about the rules. Here is the detail :  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 475, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]

Comment: it is too long so I put on the part I think is important:File "/root/autodl-tmp/project/image.py", line 12, in load_data
    index = int(img_name.split('.')[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '130(1)'

Comment: def load_data(img_path,train = True):
    img_folder = os.path.dirname(img_path)
    img_name = os.path.basename(img_path)
    # print(img_name.split('.')[0])
    index = int(img_name.split('.')[0])
    # part of original code

Comment: I meant that you should edit the question to replace the images with code blocks where you paste the text, so it can be more easily read on any device.

Comment: Oh~I have modified it ~thanks for your comments~

Comment: Please add **code blocks** around your code using three backticks: \`\`\`. You also didn't update the actual code to be text. Have you tried applying the solution I gave in my first comment?

Comment: I'll try to apply that ~ I didn't understand very well just now.

Comment: I tried to format your post a bit, but there weren’t even newlines in the code you copy-pasted. Please [edit] to fix up the code and the error message. Also please read [mre], portions of code are not very useful, it’s much better to post shortened, complete code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: When I pasted the error message, there was something wrong with the format. I copied it again and pasted the complete information above. Thanks for your kindness to modify my question and I'll learn to use this platform skillful, thank u~

Answer (score 0):

The problem mentioned in the error message:

```py
File "/root/autodl-tmp/project/image.py", line 12, in load_data index = int(img_name.split('.')[0]) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '130(1)'
```

literally means that there is an invalid character that cannot be converted to integer, in this case it's the parenthesis.

If you are looking the get the first part of the value (`49`), you can just split by the character `(` like this:

```py
def load_data(img_path,train = True):
   ...
   value = img_name.split('.')[0]
   if not value.isdecimal():
      value = value.split('(')[0]
   index = int(value)
```